# Python/flask summarization algorithm error

Tags: python, html, flask, nltk, summarization

```
@app.route('/dependent', methods = ['POST'])
def mySumD():
if request.form['action'] == 'LSA':
    para = ""
    url = request.form['url_link']
    parser = HtmlParser.from_url(url, Tokenizer(LANGUAGE))
    stemmer = Stemmer(LANGUAGE)
    summarizer = Summarizer(stemmer)
    summarizer.stop_words = get_stop_words(LANGUAGE)

    for sentence in summarizer(parser.document, SENTENCES_COUNT):
        data = str(sentence)
        para += data 
    return render_template('dependent.html', para = para)

elif request.form['action'] == 'Luhn':
    para = ""
    url = request.form['url_link']
    parser = HtmlParser.from_url(url, Tokenizer(LANGUAGE))
    stemmer = Stemmer(LANGUAGE)
    summarizer = LuhnSummarizer(stemmer)
    summarizer.stop_words = get_stop_words(LANGUAGE)

    for sentence in summarizer(parser.document, SENTENCES_COUNT):
        data = str(sentence)
        para += data 
        return render_template('dependent.html', para = para)

elif request.form['action'] == 'LexRank':
    para = ""
    url = request.form['url_link']
    parser = HtmlParser.from_url(url, Tokenizer(LANGUAGE))
    stemmer = Stemmer(LANGUAGE)
    summarizer = LexSummarizer(stemmer)
    summarizer.stop_words = get_stop_words(LANGUAGE)

    for sentence in summarizer(parser.document, SENTENCES_COUNT):
        data = str(sentence)
        para += data 
        return render_template('dependent.html', para = para)
```

>

```
<form action = "{{ url_for('mySumD') }}" method = "POST" id="urlForm" class="standard">

 <input type="url" id = "url" name="url_link" class= "form-control" placeholder="Insert URL here...">
        <div id="url_field_is_empty" class="error" style="display: none"> You must submit a valid URL</div>
  <h1>Choose Your Summarization Method</h1>
  <div class="btn-group" style="width:100%" id="subscribersoptions">
     <button style="width:20%" type ="submit" name="action" value="LSA">LSA</button>
     <button style="width:20%" type ="submit" name="action" value="Luhn">Luhn</button>
     <button style="width:20%" type ="submit" name="action" value="LexRank">Lex Rank</button>
     <button style="width:20%" type ="submit" name="action" value="TextRank">Text Rank</button>
     <button style="width:20%" type ="submit" name="action" value="SumBasic">SumBasic</button>
     <button style="width:20%" type ="submit" name="action" value="KL-Sum">KL-Sum</button>
  </div>    
  <br>
  {{para}}

</form>
```

Hello so I am having an issue with getting my flask and html to output the correct data. I am using Sumy summarization library. basically I am attempting to summarize url webpages and output the text on an html doc. Everything is working fine and dandy, particularly for my LSA summarization. The issue is that beside lsa it is only outputting the first sentence. This is why i created the para = "" variable to append strings to create a full paragraph. This works, but only for LSA. I was wondering if anyone had any inquiry into how i can get my other summarization methods to output more than 1 sentence. All these algos work fine in IDLE just not my flask app. sorry for poor english.

Comment: First thing people will ask is for you to put your code into the post instead of providing pictures of it. Would you mind doing that?

Comment: sorry, thanks first time user.

Answer (score 0):

Turn out Bob is not my Uncle. My return statements were inside the for loop instead of outside. This question has been resolved.